# Mouse event not working in Silverlight Grid

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0, tabcontrol

I Have created a Grid (g1) with a TabControl (t1). t1's TabItem content has Grid (g2). g2 has another TabControl as t20,t21,t22 (vertical TabControl) and each t2 series TabItem has another Grid (g3) .

The issue I'm having is that a mouse event is not working g3. The same function works when placed in g2.

I have tried placing a button instead of g3 and click event works, and if I add a button to g3, then the button click events work.

What could be causing the mouse event to not work?

Comment: -1 for no code. If your having issues with something, showing some code should be your first stage.

Comment: -1 from me as well. Besides what Alastair said, the gibberish `t1`, 'g2', 'g3' for variable names is terrible and makes your question hard to follow. Please don't post senseless nonsense - use actual code and variable names (and if these *are* actual variable names, shame on you).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have not given any code, however, there is a very common 'gotcha' in Silverlight regarding mouse events. An element will not raise these events unless it has a background explicitly set. Set your `Grid.Background` to `Transparent` and hopefully your events will work.

(If that doesn't work, my net guess is Z-Index!)

Comment: thank you now its working i didnt set background as transparent